# Android app communication with local apache server

Tags: php, android, apache, kotlin, android-volley

I am new to Android dev, I have started using Android Studio with Kotlin few days. I run into an issue today which is : how can my app communicate with my local server (XAMPP : Apache and MYSQL)
I am running Windows 10, and using my real physical phone instead of the emulator (API 30) since the emulator works so slow for me.

I have a simple php app that only returns "hi", I tried many ways to use AJAX requests but the one closest to working with is Android Volley, here is my code:

```
       val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://mohe.pagekite.me"
        lateinit var qq : String
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                qq = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
                val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, qq, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toast.show()
            },
            { error-> qq = error.toString()
                val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, qq, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toast.show()
            })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

at first I used my IP since we are connected to the same wifi (hotspot) and since I can actually open my localhost in my phone's browser, but it didn't work inside the code. (I had an error : `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol`), I looked around and read that Volley doesn't support IP addresses, so I used PAGEKITE to make my localhost accessible to the internet with a readable link, but now I am getting this error instead :
`cleartext http traffic to not permitted`

I added this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my manifest.xml and created network_security_config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>

        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com(to be adjusted)</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But the issue is still the same. I tried the same thing with google.com also I tried my php file but in my webhosting, and it worked just fine, so the issue is somewhere in my localhost I would assume, probably because I am not using a secure connection (https) ?

This bugged me because how else would I be able to make an app with a database if I can't comminute with my localhost ? using my real webhost slows the development process and I can't get my head around this issue. How do you develop and test your app with your local server or am I doing everything wrong ?

Edit : the purpose of my app is to be able to login and read/edit some data from any device.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: Since you have network config set to cleartextTrafficPermitted=true, you should be fine with http. Don't worry about that. I used to connect like this for time ago, most of the time, pc firewall or security system block access to you pc ports. Since you both connected to same wifi, turn off any firewall or internet security and try to call same api. Dont forget to change the domain node value to your pc local ip address (192...)

Comment: @SreehariK yes it is solved, I've already posted my solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved : I forgot to add my URL in `network_security_config.xml`

`<domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.56.172</domain>`

Now it works with both my IP address or my URL.